# Why can't obfs4 , scramblesuit and fte be used in China now?

Tags: pluggable-transports

Today, I use obfs4 ,fte and scramblesuit to connect network unsuccessfully.Are they disabled by the GFW?What happend?

Comment: It is important to disable all antivirus and firewall programs in your computer before connecting to Tor. Otherwise, the connection would be either disrupted with some error code message or no response effect.

Comment: It may work if you create your own bridge https://medium.com/@dcamero/tor-obfs4-bridge-for-gfw-5caf8db7748b#.jphibovcy

Answer (score 2):

Probably has something to do with the GFW admins deploying something like this fairly recently described classifier. All the current obfuscators seem to fall to entropy distribution, header length, and decision tree-based machine learning attacks with very low false-positive rates.

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2810103.2813715

Also, this written by the people who design the GFW:

http://crad.ict.ac.cn/CN/abstract/abstract3031.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I believe at least integrated meek-azure bridge still works, although it seems lots of bridges have been blocked recently.
How many bridges you've added? Do you check your Tor log? Any warning messages like 'connection failure?'

Comment: When I tried connecting network by such bridges,TBB shaw me it was connecting, I waited and waited but nothing happend.Do the GFW block them recently?Are you Chinese?同胞的话直接打汉字得了，说英文太见外23333

Comment: Writing in chs might against rules. Let's hope Mods here all are sleeping and let us go this time :-)

Comment: 选择自带的 meek-azure，之后的proxy设置通常可以跳过。Windows 记得关掉防火墙或设置例外，不要封了tor 相关的进程。自定义网桥，稍等一会儿，确定无法连接，查看设置窗口左下角的"点击复制tor日志"。看看卡在哪里了，10%之类的。server failure 说明那个网桥用不了。

Comment: 没什么用啊，好像所有自定义网桥都挂了，全都卡在“正在建立加密的目录” ，而且更猛的是更新到5.0.5之后meek-azure现在也用不了了@user66466

Comment: 卡在建立加密目录不一定表示网桥挂了。从Tor浏览器无法查看日志，可以修改torrc，添加一行命令：Log debug file C:\debug.txt。升级5.0.6，再试试meek，新的集成obfs4有一个应该还可以用。

Comment: 根据 Tor之前的博文 https://blog.torproject.org/blog/learning-more-about-gfws-active-probing-system，gfw还无法检测到obfs4/scramblesuit。  另外，试过几组网桥？类型呢？如果可以连上，多久会被屏蔽（用不了）？

Answer (score 0):

Obf3, Obf4, Meek-azure and Scramblesuit all works fine for me here in China. (fte looks not working)

I don't use the bundle but the vanilla Tor and I put in the config file all bridges I have together (Obf3-4, Meek-azure and scramblesuit) works pretty well :)

Now for Debian linux the packages for meek transport plugin are available so once installed you can configure tor adding this line:

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4,obfs3,scramblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec /usr/bin/meek-client
```